# How can I diagnose slow disk I/O?

Tags: release-freya, boot, startup

I downloaded Freya, installed it alongside Windows, updated it, but it's response is too slow. It takes too long to boot, files take time to open, sometimes it just gets stuck.

I checked for bad sectors but found none, checked cpu and memory usage, it's not much, checked whether too much swapping is happening, it isn't.

I really don't know what to do. I am thinking to completely wipe my disk and install Freya again. But, is there any other solution for this?

My desktop specifications are:

- 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 2GB RAM
- 500GB hard disk space

Would wiping my disk and installing it again help? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor your IO with [IOtop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

Or you can search it in the Software Center.

It is also fair to note that HDD's just aren't that fast. It could just be you expecting to much speed. The only way to solve that is to upgrade to an SSD. Reinstalling might help, but only temporary.

Comment: I know HDDs aren't that fast, but 20-30 minutes to boot, then something is  definitely wrong. Also, to open up files it used to take 5-10 minutes. I tried to wipe my disk using dban, it shows 344 hours remaining, so the problem is with my HDD, it's dying. Should have done a proper disk check. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think my HDD is dying. I tried to wipe my disk using dban and it shows 344+ hours remaining. So no problem with the Freya, it's my HDD.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if the problem is already solved (bonus: you get rewarded with rep points, too :D )